# Constrained-random assigning tasks to people for a week, non-consecutively

Tags: python, constraint-programming, constraint-satisfaction

I would like to assign randomly tasks from a list of 8 tasks to 4 people every day in a week with these conditions:

- everyone gets exactly 2 tasks per day (order doesn't matter) AND
- can't assign task to the same person on 2+ consecutive days (a person can't get the same tasks next day) AND
- can't assign same task to people on the same day AND
- a person can't do the same task more than 2 times in a week

Here is my code for one single day. But how to program the code for the 7 days in a week, enforcing the above conditions?

```
import random

tasks = ['task1','task2','task3','task4','task5','task6','task7','task8',]
people = ['person1', 'person2', 'person3', 'person4']

random.shuffle(tasks)

tasks = zip(*[iter(tasks)]*2)

for n,person in enumerate(people):
   print person, tasks[n]
```

Comment: your question should rather go to cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Pa_ that's simply not the case, programming questions are off topic there.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question a bit? What do you mean by "same task" in `same task must be assign non-consecutively`?

Comment: Yes please elaborate. Do you mean *"can't assign task<n> to 2+ people on the same day"* or *"can't assign task<n> to the same person on 2+ consecutive days'* or both? As stands the question is too vague to answer.

Comment: Either way there's some constraint on what person/task can be assigned on consecutive days. So it's a mistake to just ignore those constraints. Your assignment code for each person/task would need to lookup the previous day's assignment, which means you need to store it, into a 7xP array, where P is the number of people or 7xT, where T number of tasks. So it's a mistake to just print them without also storing them somewhere.

Comment: @smci: I understand. I edited the question. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: But you're still not storing the task assignments for each day. You need to fix that. The next day needs to look up the previous day's assignment.

Comment: There's no need to store strings 'task1',...,'task8' and 'person1',...,'person4'. Just simply **represent tasks and/or people by the integers 1..8 or 1..4** (then prettify them at printing time, if needed). Might as well use 0 for 'currently unassigned'. You can declare a numpy ndarray of 7 days x 8 tasks, whose entries . Since you have 8 tasks, 4 people, then everyone gets exactly 2 tasks per day (does order matter? do we split into half-days? for the consecutivity constraint? or is each person doing both tasks for a full day, so they can't be assigned either task the following day?)

Comment: Exactly, everyone gets exactly 2 tasks per day (order doesn't matter) but a person can't get the same tasks next day and a person can't do the same task more than 2 times in a week.

Comment: @Thammas: ok it was still somewhat ambiguous, until you edited the question again to say that.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to approach this, but one would be to just allocate them at random, check if they meet your rules, and if not then reallocate them.

I would probably do this by defining a couple of functions that you can use to check if any given allocation matches your rules.

For example:

```py
import random

def no_consecutives(allocation):
    """Check that there are no consecutive list items"""
    for i in range(1, len(allocation)):
        if allocation[i] == allocation[i-1]:
            return False
    return True

def no_more_than_twice(allocation):
    """Check that no list item appears more than twice"""
    for i in allocation:
        if allocation.count(i) > 2:
            return False
    return True

tasks = ['task1','task2','task3','task4','task5','task6','task7','task8']
people = ['person1', 'person2', 'person3', 'person4']
answer = {}
i = 0

while i < 4:
    allocations = random.choices(tasks, k=7)
    if no_consecutives(allocations) and no_more_than_twice(allocations):
        answer[people[i]] = allocations
        i += 1

print(answer)
```

Edit: Now that I've shown you how to do it, and you've edited your question to change the conditions, I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: sorry for conditions changes but reading comments, l was to vague... I've precised the constraints.

Comment: No problem whatsoever :-) Now that I've shown you one way to approach this type of problem I'll leave you to adapt it to your specific problem.

Comment: I can't figure out how to verify in the answer dictionary that items in people list are different each day. How to check that first item in each list are different ?
 `{
'person1': ['task2', 'task1', ...], 
'person2': ['task4', 'task2', ...], 
'person3': ['task2', 'task8', ...], 
'person4': ['task7', 'task1', ...]
}`
Can you guide me ?